# how to change settings in internet explorer using powershell?

Tags: internet-explorer, powershell, automation

We need to be able to change internet explorer settings on hundreds of machines.

The change that we need to make is:

1. go to settings
2. connections
3. lan settings
4. uncheck "automatically detect settings"

[image]

i know that it is possible to do change settings with something like this:

```
set-itemproperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet
Settings' -name ProxyEnable -value 1
```

**How can I change the lan settings using powershell?**

Comment: Why not just use a GPO? It is designed for this kind of thing.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart thanks! how can i do this with GPO?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart i was wondering if you could help when you had a chance

Comment: GPO means Group Policy Object. See [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit fiddly to do it that way. You can have a look at this link it could be helpful:

[What key in windows registry disables IE connection parameter "Automatically Detect Settings"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674119/what-key-in-windows-registry-disables-ie-connection-parameter-automatically-det)

The other way to do it is to make the setting manually on one server, then export the  following registry key and import it to all the servers. This will make the required change.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections\DefaultConnectionSettings
```

Comment: thanks so much for your response. what change would i make on DefaultConnectionSettings ??

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the DefaultConnectionSettings registry value is an undocumented bit array. It is not recommended to export and import as this will overwrite ALL settings stored in that registry value. The correct approach is to configure the setting in a Group Policy Object (GPO).

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов have a look at the link that I directed you to see how to make the changes, but like Bill Stewart said, it's better to do it via GPO

Comment: yes definitely the link helped a ton!! the accepted answer actually works on one of our machines but have not tested on other machines. could you point me to a resource where there's a GPO explanation about how to do such things

Comment: Here you go, this looks helpful: http://techlib.barracuda.com/display/WSFLEXv41/How+to+Configure+Proxy+Settings+Using+Group+Policy+Management

Comment: by the way what does your name mean?

Comment: haha, does it look interesting? It's an Arabic name, my first name is derived from the word hard/difficult so that's what it means. My surname is just a family name, it doesn't really have a meaning.

Comment: cool! so musaab means difficult? what significance does it have?

Comment: wow it's almost been a year since the last comment. what made you remember?  anyway to answer your question,  the name is derived from the word difficult, and it was historically used to describe an untamed horse or camel. so it signifies power and sovereignty.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

The correct approach to configure this setting is to configure it in a GPO. (As an aside, I think this question fits better at serverfault rather than stackoverflow.)

Bill

Comment: thank you, can you show me i can get started with this on GPO?

Comment: Hi, this site (stackoverflow) is not the right forum to discuss how to use GPOs. I can suggest that you can learn more by clicking the [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb310732.aspx) I provided earlier, and you probably find a lot of stuff about how to use GPOs on serverfault.