# I want to change the internet options in a programmatic way

Tags: c#, .net

I want to change my internet settings in a programmatic way.
what I do now is

1. WIN + R
2. inetcpl.cpl
3. go to connections tab
4. go to LAN settings
5. un check everything but "Use automatic configuration script"
6. give the address and exit

Can I do this with a program in c#?

Comment: If you plan to implement this for a corporate environment, consider using GPO (Group Policies) instead.

Answer (score 1):

This is -as far I can tell- the solution for your problem:

[registry key for "Use automatic configuration script"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544270/how-to-toggle-use-automatic-configuration-script)

[modify registry in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816178/modifying-the-registry-key-value)