# toggling proxy settings using powershell?

Tags: powershell, proxy

I have written a script to toggle proxy server's automatically detect settings feature. Script is running fine except it is unnecessarily checking "use a proxy server for your lan" feature as well.

[image]

here's the script:

```
$key = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet     Settings\Connections'
$data = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name  DefaultConnectionSettings).DefaultConnectionSettings

if($data[8] -eq 11)
{
$data[8] = 3
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $data
}
elseif ($data[8] -eq 3){
$data[8] = 11
Set-ItemProperty -Path $key -Name DefaultConnectionSettings -Value $data
}
```

Comment: What if you change `$data[8] = 11` in your elseif to `$data[8] = 9`? Is that the result you're after?

Comment: yes it worked. However 3 has to be changed as well, sothat when script turns it off, second option remains unchecked.

Comment: Yeah, obviously I meant for checking that you got what you wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change "$data[8] = 11" to "$data[8] = 9" and also "$data = 3" to "$data = 0".
This ensures that second option stays off.
check here:
[What key in windows registry disables IE connection parameter "Automatically Detect Settings"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1674119/what-key-in-windows-registry-disables-ie-connection-parameter-automatically-det/1674377#1674377)